# Compare string on range in SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to query a string to match within a range in the database. The table has 2 columns `FromCode` and `ToCode`.

Below is the sample data (assume the table is called `CodeList`):

```
FromCode    ToCode
IV1 0AA     IV9 9ZZ
IV10 0AA    IV28 9ZZ
IV30 0AA    IV32 9ZZ
IV36 0AA    IV36 9ZZ
IV40 0AA    IV49 9ZZ
IV51 0AA    IV56 9ZZ
IV63 0AA    IV63 9ZZ
```

So, if I run the query

```sql
SELECT *
FROM CodeList
WHERE FromCode <= 'IV1 1AB' AND ToCode >= 'IV1 1AB'
```

It would return the result

```
IV1 0AA   IV9 9ZZ
```

which is correct. But, when I run this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM CodeList
WHERE FromCode <= 'IV2 1AB' AND ToCode >= 'IV2 1AB'
```

The result I get back is

```
IV1 0AA    IV9 9ZZ
IV10 0AA   IV28 9ZZ
```

So, to a human the string `IV2 2AB` is within `IV1 0AA - IV9 9ZZ` not `IV10 0AA - IV28 9ZZ`.

If anyone could suggest a better way to search through the data it'd be much appreciated. Also, the engine I'm running this on is SQL Server 2012.

Many thanks!

Comment: compartion is lefttoright.IV2   (2) is bigger then iv10   (1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM CodeList
WHERE Cast(Substring(Replace(FromCode,' ',''),3,Len(Replace(FromCode,' ',''))-4) as int) <= Cast(Substring(Replace('IV2 1AB',' ',''),3,Len(Replace('IV2 1AB',' ',''))-4) as int)
 AND Cast(Substring(Replace(ToCode,' ',''),3,Len(Replace(ToCode,' ',''))-4) as int) >= Cast(Substring(Replace('IV2 1AB',' ',''),3,Len(Replace('IV2 1AB',' ',''))-4) as int)
```

set it in a function to make use more easy